# AngularJS $watch inexplicably changing value of the watched value

Tags: angularjs, watch, directive

I'm trying to implement an animdated version of `ng-show` and `ng-hide`; I originally tried to use `jQueryUI.toggle('slide', …)`, but since `$watch` fires multiple times, my elements were toggling in and then immediately toggling out (sometimes more than once). But I saw in AngularJS's github issues that that is $watch's intended behaviour (dirty checking).

So I thought, okay this little eff-you be damned, I'll explicitly show or hide instead of the simple toggle: I broke it down to check the value of $watch's `newValue` like so:

```
scope.$watch(condition, function myShowHideAction(newValue,oldValue) {
    if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
        if (newValue) {
            elm.show("slide", { direction: direction }, "slow");
        } else {
            elm.hide("slide", { direction: direction }, "slow");
        }
    }
}
```

Fire it up, and what do I see? Toggling!

After putting in a few console logs, I discover somehow my condition's value is being changed during $watch's loop (which iterates like 6 times instead of just once, but that should be neither here nor there). However, the actual scope parameter's value does not change (as it shouldn't) half way thru like `newValue`'s does.

What the heck is going on?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0CMdW3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because all your infoboxes share the same scope. If you put a `console.log(scope)` statement in your mySlide directives linking function, you'll see that it's created several times with the same scope. So you have multiple watches for the same condition in the same scope.

Your code isn't the easiest to follow I'm afraid, but the issue seems to be inside my-map.js on the line 87. Instead of doing `$compile(elm.contents())(scope);`, you should probably do `$compile(elm.contents())(scope.$new());` to create an isolated scope for that info box.

Comment: Hazzah! That seems to have done it—Thanks! btw my-map is based on Angular-UI's map directives (I hardly changed anything—I think just find/replace `infoWindow` for `infoBox`, so the code is largely theirs).